# Are the following Postfix and DNS configurations correct?

Tags: linux

The Linux server, 172.16.90.126, has to be able to send email to a 172.16.0.0/16 LAN. A Windows server, 172.16.90.125, with an Exchange server in it, has to be able to receive and send mail to any host on the 172.16.0.0/16 network. Internet access is not present.

Two host machines have to be able to connect to each mail server.

I need to know if the below configurations are correct.

LAN:

Servers

Linux ------------------ Windows

Host1   Host2

```
Linux Server: dm126.cst8231.com
Windows Server: dm125.cst8231.com
```

Forward Zone file: 
(Linux)

```
$ttl 38400
dm126.cst8231.com.  IN  SOA localhost.localdomain. dm126.cst8231.com (
            1517451407
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
dm126.cst8231.com.  IN  NS  localhost.localdomain.
dm125.cst8231.com.      IN      NS      localhost.localdomain.
172.16.90.126.dm126.cst8231.com.    IN  PTR dm126.cst8231.com

dm126.cst8231.com.  IN  A   172.16.90.126
dm125.cst8231.com.      IN      A       172.16.90.125
mail.dm126.cst8231.com. IN  MX  10 mail.dm126.cst8231.com.

dm126.cst8231.com.  IN  A   172.16.90.232
dm126.cst8231.com.  IN  A   172.16.91.232
```

Reverse Zone file:

In Webmin, I cannot find one!

Postfix Configurations:

```
myhostname = dm126.cst8231.com
mydomain = cst8231.com
inet_protocols = all
mynetworks = 172.16.0.0/16, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = mail.dm126.cst8231.com
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
```

Comment: Relevant question:  What is an example email address used for email in each direction?   This will impact what MX records should exist.  You might also want to think about why you have three A records for dm126.cst8231.com with different IP addresses including two on the same network (three if you are actually using 172.16.0.0/16.  It might make sense, but you should be sure and you should know why.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you cannot add PTR record in the same forward zone file.
I suggest you use `/etc/hosts` and respective windows hosts file in `%systemDrive%\windows\system32\` instead of DNS, if it's all local.